# PHP: Does $_this have a special meaning?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, frameworks, this

I cant seem to find any documentation on what `$_this` means in PHP. It seems to be used quite a bit in the CakePHP framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

CakePHP follows a general nomenclature where variables starting with `$_` are considered private to the class.  They are not important for using the framework, however.

Answer (score 4):

An underscore typically denotes the scope of the variable. A variable with a leading underscore often means that it is protected or private. This is just a convention and is not enforced by the language. It helps make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Many individuals like to use some form of variable naming convention.  In the case of private variables, people like to use `$_` as a convention.  I don't particularly know if this is the case in CakePHP, but elsewhere it's frequently seen.

Answer (score 2):

$_this is not of any PHP reserved keywords (`$this` however, is). Perhaps some kind of special variable in CakePHP.